# Give a file descriptor number, is there any way to know its type?

Tags: python, lsof

I have a program and somewhere it leaks the file descriptors, so I want to add a monitor thread to detect the process open fds, if the fd is a "PIPE" , I will close it.
I could use lsof -p or cat /proc/pid/fd to get the process number, and I could also use the grep to filtr out the TYPE, but I wonder to know if there is built-in function in python which could used to get the type of file descriptor?
something like this:

def getFdType(fd)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [`readlink`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.readlink) on the descriptor.

If the result is not a file, then its a pipe. You could also further run [`stat`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.stat):

> On some Unix systems (such as Linux), the following attributes may
>   also be available:
>
> `st_blocks` - number of 512-byte blocks allocated for file
>
> `st_blksize` - filesystem blocksize for efficient file system I/O
>
> `st_rdev` - type of device if an inode device
>
> `st_flags` - user defined flags for file